# Getting String representation of Swift ReferenceWritableKeyPath is failed (returns pointer instead of type)

Tags: swift, realm, swift-keypath

I have a `Product` class inherited from Realm `Object`:

```
@objc class Product: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: String = ""
    @Persisted var externalId: String?
    @Persisted var name: String?
}
```

I try to write a universal method for objects update which takes dictionary with keyPaths and values and update object with this Realm method:

```
func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)
```

This is a computed variable for getting String representation of KeyPath:

```
fileprivate extension KeyPath {
    var asString: String {
        let wholeString = String(describing: self)
        let dropLeading =  "\\" + String(describing: Root.self) + "."
        let keyPathString = "\(wholeString.dropFirst(dropLeading.count))"
        return keyPathString
    }
}
```

And it's perfectly works during debug mode, but when I build an app with Release scheme instead of `"Product.name"` it returns something like `"\Product.<computed 0x000000010c51ed18 (Bool)>` and the app crashed trying to set value for this keypath.

If anyone has idea how to fix this, it would be really appreciated.

Update: The idea was to encapsulate working with Realm within  class. This was the original method for updating Realm entities:

```
func updateObjects<DBEntity: Object, KeyPathType: NSObject, T>(
   ofType objectType: DBEntity.Type,
   where query: ((Query<DBEntity>) -> Query<Bool>)? = nil,
   with keyedValues: [KeyPath<KeyPathType, T>: T],
   completion: (Error?) -> Void?
)
```

The primary motivation behind using KeyPath instead of a simple String was to minimize errors and safeguard against crashes caused by changes in property names. Therefore, using `[String : T]` for the `keyedValues` parameter was not an option.

For now, it seems that Swift KeyPath is not guaranteed to be converted into a human-readable String, so that option is also unavailable.

I ended up modifying my update method to look like this:

```
func updateObjects<DBEntity: Object>(
    ofType objectType: DBEntity.Type,
    where query: ((Query<DBEntity>) -> Query<Bool>)? = nil,
    updateBlock: @escaping ([DBEntity]) -> Void,
    completion: DBOperationCompletion?
)
```

Now, I update object properties inside the `updateBlock`.

Comment: `String(describing:)` and `String(reflecting:)` are absolutely not the right tools for this job. As you see, the compiler optimizes out the property names for cases when it doesn't need them. Heck, it can even optimize out the existence of the property entirely (i.e. stored properties with a constant value can be inlined, many stored properties can be inlined just as if they were any other function). `KeyPath` doesn't provide an API for getting a String name out, and that's intentional, because it would be a huge barrier for all those kinds of optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It seems that I have to rethink the update method for repository without using swift keypaths.

Comment: Indeed, use `String` if String is what you really mean

Comment: Not sure why this is being done. Why not just set the property on the object instead of calling a function to do it? `someProduct.name = "soap"`. Realm objects can also have multiple properties created or upserted via key:value pairs like this `let p = Product(value: ["id": "1", "name": "soap"])`. Perhaps if the use case was clearer, we may be able to provide a more definitive answer. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I updated the post, added the use case. The idea was to encapsulate updating realm objects but make it safe from mistakes due to properties name changing.

Comment: @AlexSh. hmm this looks like the perfect use case for something like C#’s [`nameof` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof). There’s nothing like that built into Swift, but lucky for you, macros just launched, and you can add one! The [`#stringify`](https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax/blob/main/Examples/Sources/MacroExamples/Implementation/Expression/StringifyMacro.swift) macro does pretty much exactly that!